# AJAX call not executing web method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

The Simple code below

```
<div class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSearch">Search</div>

<script src="<% = Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-latest.js") %>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'MenuBackoffice.aspx/onSearch',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { },
                    success: function (msg) {

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    [WebMethod]
    public static void onSearch()
    {

    }
```

Is not reaching my WebMethod, i don't know what is wrong, can someone add some light?

EDIT: In the debug i'm getting the following error:
ailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: is jquery loading ?

Comment: and also have you tried to put  a /  in front of your url? .. like : url: '/MenuBackoffice.aspx/onSearch',

Comment: That is a server-side error (the clue is in the "Internal *Server* Error") :) Enable full errors display on your server to see the actual bug

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi: It would have been a 404 if that were the problem.

Comment: It could certainly be reaching your WebMethod, which then produces an unhandled exception. Add debugging or logging code to make sure what is happening.

Comment: @GoneCoding: with custom Errors Off:  [ArgumentException: Unknown web method onSearch.
Parameter name: methodName]

Comment: Can you post your C# code that has the onSearch method?  Is it flagged with the proper WebMethod attribute?  And is the case for the method name the exact same?

Comment: Can you update your question and change the title?  This isn't matter of a redirect.  It's a case of your AJAX call not executing your web method.

Comment: @EricBurdoThe code is exactly like that, empty. I'll change the title.

Comment: Turns out the error changed after i removed all the dlls and rebuild the code: Message
:
"An attempt was made to call the method 'onSearch' using a GET request, which is not allowed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to clean and build the solution and after that the error changed to "An attempt was made to call the method 'onSearch' using a GET request, which is not allowed."

EDIT: Adding Nagaraj Raveendran solution - Instead use GET in ajax method, without having to use the ScriptMethod.

Comment: Good. Instead try using GET in ajax method, without having to use the ScriptMethod.

Comment: That's even better. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

add the below code to routeconfig.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("MenuBackoffice.aspx/onSearch");
```

If this does not work, URL might be an issue. Try changing url: in ajax call.

```
'<%= ResolveUrl("MenuBackoffice.aspx/onSearch") %>'
```

Comment: Suggested an another change you could try to make it work in the answer.

Comment: Got the same error:
Unknown web method onSearch.
Parameter name: methodName